# Getting errors in sendmail log

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, sendmail, amazon-ses

I am using Amazon SES for sendmail in my Linux Centos.

I am send `500` mails and this is what i get in sendmail log

what does it mean

```
Jul 22 19:09:15 server sendmail[1117]: rejecting connections on daemon MTA: load average: 20
Jul 22 19:09:30 server sendmail[1117]: rejecting connections on daemon MTA: load average: 16
Jul 22 19:09:45 server sendmail[1117]: rejecting connections on daemon MTA: load average: 12
Jul 22 19:10:00 server sendmail[1117]: accepting connections again for daemon MTA

Jul 22 19:08:39 server sm-msp-queue[16168]: runqueue: Flushing queue from /var/spool/clientmqueue/r6MA2fDB014603 (pri 32204, LA 26, 110 of 115)
```

Comment: Could you post QueueLA, RefuseLA and DelayLA settings in your sendmail.cf file?

Answer (score 2):

By default, sendmail will start denying connections if the load average gets too high. When the load average drops, it will accept connections again. This type of behavior is built into the SMTP spec, and it shod not cause any issues for you.

Comment: by denying means those emails will be lost untill load becomes normal

Comment: No, it does not. Please, do yourself a favor and read up on how SMTP works.